# Questions Regarding Tabular Data and Implementing Machine Learning Methods on it

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression

I have a .csv data set (N = 140) that I want to perform analysis on. Specifically, I want to find a relationship between the .csv's "P" (Predictor) cells and the "T" (Target) cells (pictured below). T_Summed is simply the sum of the T cells and P_Avg is simply the average of the P cells. An observation containing these values is pictured below.

[image]

Using R, nearly every combination of running the P's against the T's (one variable against another) leads to a scatter plot that looks like this:

[image]

Some of them have slightly more randomness/spread, but all of them had at least some data points with the 'vertical' shape shown in the plot above. My issue lies in the fact that I have extremely minimal knowledge of statistics or data analysis, so I do not know how to run an appropriate model that will fit a plot of this shape, how to validate it, and, if using a model with multiple independent variables, how to visualize it. The only things I know how to do are run a simple linear model, a multiple linear model (don't know how to visualize this), and a potentially misused k-folds cross validation. Here's an example of how I created one of the linear models in question with repeated k-folds cross validation:

```
ex <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 5)
simple_reg_model <- train(`T_Summed` ~
                 `P_Avg`,
               data = data, 
               method = "lm",
               trControl = ex)
```

I am afraid that my lack of knowledge in statistics will lead me to search around the internet and almost arbitrarily implement solutions that I have little understanding of, thus making my analysis faulty, inaccurate, or misleading. Due to this, I decided to consult the statistics StackExchange with a few questions:

1. Is the code block above, at least for a linear model, an acceptable way of using repeated CV?
2. What alternative models should I possibly begin to explore for this data? How might I go about learning about how to implement them properly?
3. Models with multiple IVs appear to me to be difficult to plot. If anyone has a suggestion for question number 2. that involves multiple IVs, how might I go about plotting them so that they are interpretable?
4. Another question regarding multiple IV models: I do not know how to use feature selection. If anyone has a suggestion for number 2., how would you go about selecting features for your suggestion?

I very much appreciate any support.

Thank you

Comment: "*My issue lies in the fact that I have extremely minimal knowledge of statistics or data analysis, so I do not know how to run an appropriate model (...), how to validate it, and, if using a model with multiple independent variables, how to visualize it.*" Read a nice introductory book. Maybe [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www.statlearning.com/) or [Applied Predictive Modeling](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/). It will pay out tenfold compared to a stranger on the Internet answering a specific question. Or get a coauthor who can do Stats/ML, that works (mid-term) too.